# sass compiler has generated two css files and i can only attach one css into the index.html

Tags: css, sass

My SASS compiler was working just fine and I could see the styles responding in the live web server but then it stopped. I noticed the extension has generated another CSS file. my original CSS file into which compilation is done is called "styles.css" but now it generated another one called `header.css` and it's not compiled to `styles.css`. The styles are not working in the live web server because in my `index.html` I have linked `styles.css` as my source file.

[image]

Comment: Quick fix ? just concatenate them together (eg: copy/paste the contents of header.css into styles.css (above the current content).

Comment: As for the reason it happened in the first place, or as to what the proper fix is: you'll have to add some information on what compiler you're using (+ version) and which (if any) options are in effect (either cli arguments to the compiler or rc files or w/e).

Comment: live scss compiler compiles each file's scss to a css file that has the same name. if there seems to be an issue in those compiled files, delete the css and save the scss files to recompile them. otherwise check your scss files for error

Answer (score 0):

turns out i made a mistake while creating the "header.scss" file as one of my sass files beacause i didnt create it as a partial file (_header.scss) i forgot to put the underscore at the beggining. i think sass compiler was sorting it separately because it considered it as a whole file thus was compiled separately. Thanks

Special thanks to Anuja Nimesh and others, you gave me the idea to check my scss file for error and i found one, now i can continue codding. I will come back with questions if am stuck again.